# Bad Request 400 and deserialization error while testing api using rest assured put method

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am testing endpoint with path para and query para and updating the request with some parameters. When I send the request content type is json 
and request looks good with the data that i am trying to change however when response is received

**content type is text 
and i get 400 error bad request as status code 
and error message**

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't infer a type for unmarshalling into: java.util.List

my code

```
@Given("^api is set up with required details$")
public void api_is_set_up_with_user_data() throws Throwable {
    loadProp();
    base_url = prop.getProperty("baseurl");
    RestAssured.baseURI = base_url;

}

@When("^a user retrieves the preferences by userid \"([^\"]*)\" and type \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void a_user_retrieves_the_preferences_by_userid_and_type(String userid, String parameter) throws Throwable {
    request = given().pathParam("user_id", userid).queryParam("type", parameter);
    System.out.println(request);
    ENDPOINT_GET_USER_BY_ID = base_url + "{user_id}/preferences";
    response = request.when().get(ENDPOINT_GET_USER_BY_ID);
    System.out.println("response: " + response.prettyPrint());
}

@Then("^updates the value \"([^\"]*)\" of name \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void updates_the_value_of_name(String value, String displaytext) throws Throwable {
    HashMap<String,String> post = new HashMap<String,String>();
    post.put("displaytext",displaytext);
    post.put("value",value);
    response = request.contentType("application/json").accept("*/*").body(post).put(ENDPOINT_GET_USER_BY_ID);
//        response = request.header("Content-Type", "application/json").body(post).put(ENDPOINT_GET_USER_BY_ID);

    System.out.println("Response : " + response.asString());
    System.out.println("Statuscode : " +response.getStatusCode());

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the said `PUT` endpoint, and its definition? How is it declared in the controller maybe? It seems there is a `List` definition in its RQ body, but you are not sending one, your RQ body in test must be incorrect. Maybe rather than `{}`, you have to send `[ {} ]`, so a list in the root?

Comment: endpoint is http://localhost:8080/users/variable1/preferences?type=somevariable

request = given().pathParam("variable1", variabble1).queryParam("somepara", parameter);

Comment: [
    {
        "displayText": "",
        "preferences": [
            {
                "category": "",
                "displaytext": "",

            }
        ],
        "priority": "20"
    },
    {
        "mandatory":,
        "name": "",
        “preferences”: [
            {
                "category": "",
                "displaytext": "",

            },
            {
                "category": "",
                "value":
            }, ],
        "priority": "30"
    }
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have shared in your comment there, the endpoint is expecting a list of objects, not a singular object as you are sending... Just try wrapping that with a list, and you'd get past 400 error.

What you are sending;

```
{
    "displayText": "Warrants", 
    "value": "true"  // I don't know about this value field here
}
```

What is expected, as you've shared;

```
[ 
    {
        "displayText": "", 
        "preferences": [ { "category": "", "displaytext": "", } ], 
        "priority": "20" 
    }
]
```

One issue is that you have to send the object in a list, also passing objects as map is also somewhat counter productive, better to use the same object used in the RQ.

```
public class Request {

    private String displayText;
    private List<Preference> preferences;
    private Integer priority;

    //getter, setter,etc
}
```

& use it in your body in the rest assured test;

```
List<Request> requestList = new ArrayList<>();
Request request = new Request();
request.setDisplayText("etc");
... // set other stuff
requestList.add(request);
response = request.contentType("application/json").accept("*/*").body(requestList).put(ENDPOINT_GET_USER_BY_ID);
```

Comment: I tried this
    JsonArray arr = new JsonArray(); 
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
 JsonObject requestparams = new JsonObject();
        requestparams.addProperty("displayText", "");
        requestparams.addProperty("name", "Products");
        obj.addProperty("displaytext",displaytext);
        obj.addProperty("value",value);
        arr.add(obj);
        requestparams.add("preferences", obj);

however again i had same issue..
thanks for your reply...will try your solution and let you know

Comment: Not yet.. its a bit long request so creating getter setter for them.. thats what I understand.. is it possible to read json file... change it to string and replace the node value and use it to hit endpoint???

Comment: not exactly.. will post the exact solution tomorrow in the morning once i reach my desk... thanks for your help and following up....... your solution helped me drill down further and find exact solution. thanks

Comment: JSONArray responseJson = new JSONArray(response.asString());
  for (int idx = 0; idx < responseJson.length(); idx++) {
            JSONObject subCat = responseJson.getJSONObject(idx);
            JSONArray prefs = subCat.getJSONArray("preferences");
            for (int prefidx =0; prefidx < prefs.length(); prefidx++) {
                JSONObject pref = prefs.getJSONObject(prefidx);
                if (pref.getString("name").equals(displaytext)) {
                    // Match, update value
                    pref.put("value", value);
                }
            }
        }